# What Should I do with NaN Values when Transforming Categorial Data to Numerical Data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pandas, data-cleaning

I'm currently working on a dataset with several categorial features, which I need to transform into numerical features through one hot encoding.

However, some of the features have `NaN` values in them. I understand that, for numerical features, these should be replaced by the feature's mean value to avoid any issues, but I'm unsure of what to do for categorical features.

Will I lose any information if I don't include `NaN` as a category? What's the typical approach to this situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each sample with `NaN` category, find the most relevant samples with actual value in that feature, based on other features or label similarity, then use the commonly used feature to replace 'NaN' in the sample.